# How to format negative currency numbers in Flask and jinja

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

In Flask/jinja I am trying to reformat a number in

```
  {{ "${:,.2f}".format(row['total']) }}
```

It is for buying/selling stocks so I would like the number to be presented as $1000 for bought and -$1000 for sold (bonus points if I can format the negative number in red too!)

The problem with the above formatting, it gives $1000 for a positive amount and $-1000 for a negative amount

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom `jinja2` filter.

for more organization, you can dedicate a separated file `filters.py` for all your custom `jinja2` filters just like `forms.py` or `models.py`

in `filters.py`

```
from numbers import Number
from decimal import Decimal

from jinja2 import Markup


def format_currency(value):
    if not isinstance(value, (Number, Decimal)):
        raise TypeError("Value must be Number.")
    if value < 0:
        return Markup'<span style="color:red">- </span>' + format_currency(-value))
    return "${:,.2f}".format(value)
```

in your main file where you instantiate your `Flask` app, register you custom `jinja2` filter like

```
from falsk import Flask, ...
from .filters import format_currency

..
app = Flask(__name__)

app.jinja_env.filters['format_currency'] = format_currency

..
```

in your template

```
<p>{{ 0 | format_currency }}</p>
<p>{{ 1000 | format_currency }}</p>
<p>{{ 1000.12654 | format_currency }}</p>
<p>{{ -1000 | format_currency }}</p>
<p>{{ 2151000 | format_currency }}</p>
<p>{{ -2151000 | format_currency }}</p>
```

and this will output:

```
$0.00
$1,000.00
$1,000.13
- $1,000.00
$2,151,000.00
- $2,151,000.00
```