# Jinja2 how to format a number with thousands separator and round to two digits?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to format a number like this `250,000.50`

What I have tried

```
<td style="text-align:right;">${{"{0:,.2f}"|format(data[0]['amount']) }} </td>
<td style="text-align:right;">${{"{:0.2f}"|format(data[0]['amount']) }} </td>
<td style="text-align:right;">${{"{0:%.2f}"|format(data[0]['amount']) }} </td>
```

data[0]['amount'] contains 250000.505050

Comment: have a look at this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729514/12368419

Comment: @cizario no other way to format?

Comment: @Deiakk96 The linked answer appears to answer your question, albeit with some python code to make the custom filter work.  It *should* allow you to use a tag like `{{ data[0]['amount'] | format_currency }}` ...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work.

```
<td style="text-align:right;">{{ "{:,.2f}".format(data[0]['amount']) }}</td>
```

result: 38,267.00 with random data